# Using properties file in Java: copy key value and assign it to another key

Tags: java

is it possible to achieve below scenario using properties file in Java. Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Assume I have a settings.properties file which includes,

```
my.name=${name}
his.name=hisNameIs${name}
```

In my code,

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("path/settings.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("my.name", "John");
prop.load(input);
String output=  prop.getProperty(his.name);
System.out.println(output);
```

Expected Results:

```
hisNameIsJohn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution using `org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration`

```
PropertiesConfiguration prop = new PropertiesConfiguration(new File("path/settings.properties"));
    prop.addProperty("name", "John");
    prop.getProperty(his.name);
```

In, "settings.properties" file.

```
his.name=hisNameIs${name}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) Project has an implementation capable of doing variable interpolation.

Read the section named Variable Interpolation

```
application.name = Killer App
application.version = 1.6.2
application.title = ${application.name} ${application.version}
```

You would need this third-party library in your class path, but on the other hand you will not have to worry about writing yet another implementation for this :)

You might like to read the [Properties How To](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html) as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, able to resolve this using org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration

Comment: My answer should be the accepted answer.